# Is making an acceptable 3D engine possible using only SDL_* functions?

Tags: opengl, 3d, sdl

I've been watching Javidx9's 3D engine series and I decided to start making it with SDL because it was something I had heard of and seemed simple enough. I'm not going to implement too complex graphical features anyway. So I start writing code, and I'm drawing my triangles with SDL_DrawLine(), and I'm filling my triangles with SDL_DrawLine, and I go to load up the Utah Teapot and the frames are stuttering quite a bit. I'm pretty sure I already know the answer to this question but I want to be sure: **Is it unrealistic to try to create a 3D engine without using raw OpenGL funcions?** It would make sense that the frames are so bad because SDL would have to work through something like OpenGL so I'm just calling an abstracted DrawLine function that's just making the computer do extra stuff and slowing it down.

By the way, I do know that SDL has OpenGL, but I (naively?) figured it would just be easier to go without it.

Comment: "acceptable" by whom? You are the ultimate arbiter of whether your solution is meeting your needs. From your description, it sounds like **you** find your current solution unacceptable. Would you like to edit your question to ask something like "How can I improve the performance of my SDL renderer" - including code samples and profiling results to clarify what you're dealing with? Then folks can recommend ways to speed it up - whether there are native SDL techniques that you can use more efficiently, or whether direct OpenGL use is the only route.

Comment: Software rendering is very much a thing, but it typically would not use higher level constructs like SDL_Draw* calls. Instead you would have a single bitmap representing your framebuffer, and write your own low-level renderer writing it's output to that. This can perform well with low resolution and low complexity scenes, but the code is an order of magnitude more complex than something like OpenGL or Direct3D. So if you're preferring SDL because it seems simpler, you probably don't want to do that.